# Covariance of a non-stationary AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, arima, covariance, stationarity

I have the following AR(2) process:

$(1+B^{2})X_t=Z_t$ where $X_0=X_1=0$ and $t=1,2,3...$

This is clearly not stationary since the roots are **i**,**-i** and therefore have modulus of 1 (i.e on the boundary of the unit circle).

How do we find $\text{Cov}(X_t, X_s)$ for  any nonnegative integers *$\text{t}$* and *$\text{s}$* ? I am not sure how to proceed since this has no stationary solution.

Comment: Hi: the standard way would be to get $X_t$ in terms of a sum of $Z_t$ but I don't know how to do that in this case because $X_t = \frac{Z_t}{1+B^2}. $ Maybe someone does know and then then problem becomes pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly,
\begin{align}
  X_2 &=-X_0 + Z_2,
\\X_4 &=+X_0 - Z_2 + Z_4,
\\X_6 &=-X_0 + Z_2 - Z_4 + Z_6
\end{align}
and so on, with similar expressions for odd $t$.

Hence, for $i\in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, $k\in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $h \in \{0,1\}$, the conditional covariances are
$$
\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}
\Cov(X_{2i+h},X_{2(i+k)+h}|X_0,X_1)=(-1)^k \sigma^2 i,
$$
where $\sigma^2=\Var(Z_t)$.
All other covariances are zero.